# DateTime conversion with Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Date/Time they come from a Apache server in this format :

2011-05-20T14:21:00.103-04:00

How I can convert this Date/Time to NSDate...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You'll need to specify the [`dateFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBEDIHH), and the patterns you can use are [available here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-05-20T14:21:00.103-04:00"];
```

Comment: This method does not exist on iOS.

Comment: It's deprecated in iOS. I didn't notice iphone tag. Btw `strftime()` will work fine even in iOS. So there is  still a one-liner possibility